# Primary Key Error while importing table Using Sqoop

Tags: import, primary-key, sqoop

I tried to import all tables using the sqoop into one of the directories.But one of the tables has no primary key.This is the code I executed.

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera/retail_db" 
--username=retail_dba 
--password=cloudera 
--warehouse-dir  /user/cloudera/sqoop_import/
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error during import: No primary key could be found for table
>   departments_export. Please specify one with --split-by or perform a
>   sequential import with '-m 1'.

By seeing 
[sqoop import without primary key in RDBMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138498/sqoop-import-without-primary-key-in-rdbms)

I understood that we can just use `--split-by` for a single table import.Is there a way i can specify `--splity-by` for `Import-all-tables` command. Is there a way I can use more than one mapper for the multi-table import with no primary-key.

Answer (score 8):

you need to use [--autoreset-to-one-mapper](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism):

Tables without primary key will be imported with one mapper and others with primary key with default mappers (4 - if not specified in `sqoop` command)

- As @JaimeCr said you can't use `--split-by` with `import-all-tables` but this just a quote from sqoop guide in context of error you got:

  > If a table does not have a primary key defined and the `--split-by> <col>` is not provided, then import will fail unless the number of mappers is explicitly set to one with the `--num-mappers 1` or `--m 1` option or the `--autoreset-to-one-mapper` option is used.
- The option `--autoreset-to-one-mapper` is typically used with the `import-all-tables` tool to automatically handle tables without a primary key in a schema.

  ```
  sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera/retail_db" \
  --username=retail_dba \
  --password=cloudera \
  --autoreset-to-one-mapper \
  --warehouse-dir  /user/cloudera/sqoop_import/
  ```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that option.